# Time string to Calendar

Tags: spring, datetime, jquery-plugins, timepicker

I am using the jquery timepicker plugin and it works fine. I can select a time and submit my form. I am using spring MVC 3.0 and the problem comes in when I attempt to parse a string ,which represents time, as a java carlendar.

I have been reading up on this date/time conversion, http://www.odi.ch/prog/design/datetime.php, and it seems quite complicated. Can someone please offer some form of advice. Here is my code, which is spring specific.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "scheduleadd", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String scheduleadd(  @Valid Schedule schedule, BindingResult bindingResult,
                            @RequestParam("startdate") @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) java.util.Calendar startdate,
                            @RequestParam("enddate") @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.DATE) java.util.Calendar enddate,
                            @RequestParam("starttime") @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.NONE) java.util.Calendar starttime,
                            @RequestParam("endtime") @org.springframework.format.annotation.DateTimeFormat(iso=ISO.NONE) java.util.Calendar endtime,
                            @RequestParam("moduleInstanceId") Long mId, Model uiModel, HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest) { //my stuff goes here}
```

As you can see, I am trying to parse a string like "09:30" as java Carlendar. Do I need the date part? How do I specify the date part ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `pattern` attribute of [@DateTimeFormat](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/format/annotation/DateTimeFormat.html) to specify that the "time" fields are not fully-formed ISO datetimes, but rather just times; e.g.:

```
...
@RequestParam("starttime") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="hh:mm") Calendar starttime,
@RequestParam("endtime") @DateTimeFormat(pattern="hh:mm") Calendar endtime,
...
```

And in your `scheduleadd()` method, combine the `Calendar` fields to get a fully-formed datetime:

```
startdate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, starttime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
startdate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, starttime.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
...
```